# How to sync live server html and directly from folder?

Tags: html, file

I am new to web development and has started 2 days ago, and I get a problem with running my HTML. If I try to open my file directly from a folder while the path I Code is `/images/works/5.jpg` instead of the full path it says error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, but on the live server, through VsCode it works perfectly. And if I try to open it using full path it only works from the folder instead, not working using a live server.
I'm sorry to ask this long I am really new to this community, and may I use chrome instead of firefox because I understand it on chrome but not in firefox?? (because on youtube everyone seems like firefox)

Answer (score 0):

The URL starts with `/`. That's an absolute path.

If you open it from a page loaded from `http://localhost/something.html` then you get `http://localhost/images/etc`.

If you open it from a page loaded from `file:///home/users/websites/something.html` then you get `file:///images/etc`.

That one breaks is expected.

Websites were designed to be loaded from web servers, so don't worry about the latter case. Just load the page from the server.

The browser you use doesn't matter. The behaviour is standard across them all.

Comment: Thank you sir for answering my question, I'll try to change it and that mean which one I should use sir?